# MVC3 Models, EF and SQL Relationship

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, many-to-many

I had a property in my `MoveItems` table called `MoveItemSubCat`. Up until now, I was thinking that I would provide a pre-populated `dropdownlist` of `MoveItemSubCat`, and the user would just select and it would go into DB.

So if the user already has an item with a `MoveItemSubCat` in the SQL DB, how would I make that the selected value in the view? Is this possible or do I need to make another table called `MoveItemSubCats` with all my `SubCategories`? This seems like it's going the way of a `many-to-many` relationship with a junction table of `MoveItemSubCats_MoveItems`.

Is a `many-to-many` the correct way to do this? Or can I get away with having a `dropdownlistfor` with values that go into 1 table column called `MoveItemSubCat`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to keep your db normalized, then you are going to want to go with a lookup table, for example:

```
MoveItemSubCat
-------------------------------
Id     int
Code   nvarchar(100)
```

If, in your original table, you change `MoveItemSubCat` to `MoveItemSubCatId   int,` and make it a `FK to the Id column in MoveItemSubCat`, EF will pickup the relationship in your entity model and objects.

Comment: And how exactly would I display the dropdown list if I now have my SubCat Names living in my db?

Comment: Using EditorFor for your MoveItems model.

Comment: Hmmm. Why wouldn't I use dropdownlistfor?